# Why the div not coming on next line when float the ul to right?

Tags: html, css

I want to do `ul` and `div` in a separate line and also the `ul` should display in the right corner. When I use the `float` property on ul and `li` its goes to right side but the `div` also comes on the above line, why its happing i also use `:after` and `:before` of `ul` and used `clear` property too, but dont getting the proper output.

https://jsfiddle.net/rawat/4kd4y2zz/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
<div>
    Hello Its a Full Article
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
    display:block;
    list-style:none;    
}
ul:after, ul:before{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
ul li{
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
div{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `clear: both` (or right) to `div`.

```
div {clear: both}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4kd4y2zz/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4kd4y2zz/2/)**

CSS:

```
ul{
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
    display:block;
    list-style:none;  
    background:grey;
}
ul:after, ul:before{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
ul li{
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
div{
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
     background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put following attribute in div CSS:

```
clear:both;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways using which you can achieve expected result

**CSS**

```
div {
  clear:both
}

ul:after{
  content: '';
  display:block '';
  clear:both;
}
```

Or you can add an extra `<div></div>` into your DOM with style `clear:both`